# FATAL: database “postgres” is not currently accepting connections

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I am on linux ubuntu, it seems i have blocked my self after running `update pg_database set datallowconn = false;` so now all the database including postgres, template0 and template1 do not accept connections, when i try to connect it keeps saying

> FATAL: database "postgres" is not currently accepting connections

I am using postgresql version 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, that is quite a pickle.

You will have to start up the server [in single-user mode](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/app-postgres.html), which bypasses the check, and then update pg_database again.